# How can I find out which folder http://localhost:3000 points to?

Tags: command-line, powershell, localhost, node.js, ports

When I open a windows 10 command prompt or powershell and navigate to a folder with a ReactJS app, then run `npm start` this opens up `http://localhost:3000` in my default browser.

What should happen is the React app I've served should run at that port, however a completely different page loads. It is a page I recognise from a past tutorial I followed, however I can't find the files relating to that project.

To complicate matters, localhost:3000 always points to this folder, even after a reboot with no npm server running, or any other web server to my knowledge.

I can only imagine that somehow port 3000 is mapped to a given folder.

I've checked the windows hosts file and that's empty, and have rebooted several times, but cannot figure out why this is happening.

I've also run `netstat -ab` to see if I can identify what's using the port, but it's not listed in the output.

I realise I could specify a different port to bypass the issue, but I'd like to get to the bottom of it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Ports are not mapped to folders. Processes are listening on ports and can do whatever. // Make sure you aren't viewing cached data in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel B's comment, I managed to figure out that a cached version of the page was running under that port via a service worker.

To fix, I went to the Application tab in Chrome DevTools and deleted the service worker and now it works fine.